why is $L=\{\{x\mid x<q(i)\}\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ not the set of all Dedekind cuts?
Let the set $L$ be definded as
$$L=\{\{x\mid x<q(i)\}\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\},$$
where $q(i)$ is some bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.
Clearly, every member of $L$ is neither an empty set nor $\mathbb{Q}$.
Every member of $L$ is closed downward.
Every member of $L$ has no largest member.
So, all members of $L$ are Dedekind cuts.
If $L$ is the set of all possible Dedekind cuts, then real numbers would be countably infinite. So, my question is, why is $L$ not the set of every possible Dedekind cut?

Edit:
I'm aware that irrational numbers are not included in $L$.
So to clarify my question, how could $\{x\mid x^2<2\lor x<0\}$ be not in $L$ although $L$ has all possible cuts corresponding to every single rational number?
I'm looking for explanation, not a counter example.

The set ${x : x\leq 0 \text{ or } x^2 \leq 2 }$ is a Dedekind cut which is not in your set $L$ (it's the real number $\sqrt{2}$).

No irrational belongs to your set!

$q(i)$ is not a bijection, $q$ is the bijection.

Just for one example, $D={x\in\mathbb Q\mid x\leq 0\lor x^2<2}$ is a Dedekind cut that is not in $L.$

In fact, $L$ is the canonical identification of $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R$. So really, any choice of irrational will do

To hopefully give some intuition: why do you have any reason to believe that $L$ should exhaust the set of Dedekind cuts? You're right that every member of $L$ is a cut, of course, but that's not unlike saying that every square is an integer; yes, but that doesn't tell you anything about any non-square integers, and your set $L$ doesn't say anything about cuts that might not be in it.

@StevenStadnicki What makes me think that is for example every single cut of rational that is less than the square root of 2 is in $L$. That makes me expect that the cut corresponding to the irrational should be included somehow in $L$.

But it doesn't, because for every rational $q(i)$ such that ${x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\leq 0\vee x^2\lt 2}\subseteq {x \in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\lt q(i)}$, there exists a rational $q(j)$ with $q(j)\lt q(i)$ and ${x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\leq 0\vee x^2\lt 2}\subseteq {x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x\lt q(i)}$. So the set cannot equal anything in $L$.

Is your question really "How come my intuition tells me something wrong?" Because you are asking why you expect something false to be true, but will not accept a simple counterexample as evidence that what you "expect" is just not so. To quote Mark Twain: it's not what you don't know, it's what you "know" that just ain't so.

Your definition of the family $L$ is unnecessarily complicated.  Since we already know that $\mathbb Q$ is countable, we can simply define your countable family $L$ to be the family of sets $\{x\in\mathbb Q : x < i\}$ as $i$ ranges over $\mathbb Q$.  This makes it more obvious that you have simply defined the Dedekind cuts corresponding to the rationals.
Taking your favorite irrational, say $\pi$, you get a Dedekind cut $\{x\in\mathbb Q : x<\pi\}$ not in $L$.

This might be an approach to consider.
If I understand your definition of $L$, it appears to be equivalent to a "rational cut."  That is, $L$ is associated with the rational number $q$, or perhaps call it the rational cut $L\left(q\right)$.  In that case, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is the least upper bound of the set $L\left(q\right).$  Each set of form $L$ likewise has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}.$
Now, in the second case $\{x | x^{2} \lt 2 \lor x \lt0 \}$, this set does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}.$  This is shown in Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis (3rd Ed.) in Example 1.9 (discussing Example 1.1).  So, it is different than the family of sets $L\left(q\right)$, but still a cut.

Your answer made me think again about this particular cut. Let $H={q(i)\mid q^2(i)>2 \land q(i)>0}$, now does every single member of $H$ has a corresponding cut in $L$? I think the answer is yes including the cut ${x\mid x^2<2 \lor x<0}$.
